# Why the polynomial $x^6-6x^2+3$ is not solvable by radicals over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, symmetric-groups

I am stuck with it. How to find the Galois group of this polynomial. Any hint will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Rethink. $x^2=y$.

Comment: Oo I see thanks a lot!

Comment: Wolfram Alfa shows the roots [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E6-6x%5E2%2B3) and demonstrates that none of these are rational. I don't know the theory but the solutions show that it is so.